# How to read media files with normal file reading functions in C/C++?

Tags: c, media

I only have experience with normal text/binary files. Now, I want to process more advanced file formats, such as media files (video/audio) without using external library like `libav` and `ffmpeg`. The purpose is to understand the principles for processing these files.

However, I can't seem to find a basic tutorial on learning this subject on the internet. Does any one know some useful resources? Also, how can I process it "raw" from the file such as ".mp4", ".mp3"...

Comment: Different files have different headers. For instance a bmp file has a bitmap file header first in the file, while a wav has a header followed of sequence of data chunks. You will need to read the specification for the file format and then parse the file based on the specification. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format and https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Comment: For audio, the simplest format is WAV, which stores uncompressed sound wave. I made a simple WAV player myself same time ago... this article may be a good resource: http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a broad question. What exactly do you want to do? Do you have a specific goal that you need to accomplish (getting one format to another)? In that case, use FFmpeg/Libav to transcode. Are you interesting in learning how to do this stuff for the sake of learning? That's cool, too. Read on.

It sounds like you already have audio formats in mind. One task might be to take a simple audio format (like .WAV or .AIFF) that is encoded with a simple audio codec (e.g., a variation of ADPCM) and process if (i.e., open the file, parse the header, decode the data, and, optionally, send it to an audio output interface to play it).

[The MultimediaWiki](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/) is a free online resource for technical multimedia information (disclosure: I run the site). It should have some information to help you along. Let me know if you want to go deeper into multimedia tech.

**UPDATE:**
Here are some specific, audio-oriented goals that you can try: Look at some of the files from this directory: http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/A-codecs/libsndfile-samples/ (I generated these a few years ago; [here's information about how I did it](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/libsndfile-survey-caff/)). I recommend studying the following files: aif-ima-adpcm.aif, wav-ima-adpcm.wav, and wav-ms-adpcm.wav. Figure out how to parse them, decode the audio inside, and output them to the audio device on your computer. Some resources to help you get started:

- [WAV format](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Microsoft_Wave)
- [AIFF format](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Audio_Interchange_File_Format)
- [IMA ADPCM algorithm](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=IMA_ADPCM)
- [Microsoft ADPCM algorithm](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Microsoft_ADPCM)
- Assuming you are on Linux, look at [PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User) or [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Documentation) for playing your decoded PCM

Good luck! And don't hesitate to ask more questions (though they should probably be separate SO questions so this entry doesn't get too unwieldy).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I want to do this just for the sake of learning. However, I want to implement a few simple formats just to get a glimpse on how the multimedia is actually processed in the computer. Just like many subjects we learned in university, we may not use it directly, but it will be useful later when we really need to work on it, we have the foundation to dig into the field . And I want to learn it from the ground up, not by using the libraries.

Comment: I applaud your thirst for knowledge. I'll update my answer with some specific examples.